# Django auth Real time effect

Tags: python, django, authentication, real-time, django-authentication

i am opening the shell command for django
python manage.py shell

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
print authenticate(username='q80', password='nokia6230') #result q80
```

now if i logged in django admin site /admin 
and changed the password and return to the shell
if i am using the old values still authenticate!

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
print authenticate(username='q80', password='newpassword') #result None
print authenticate(username='q80', password='nokia6230') #result q80
```

if close the shell session and open it again its work!

how can i have realtime change effect!?

Comment: Have you try to check on the database if anything has changes after you change the password on the admin? I'm also wondering if any of your authentication backends is caching

Comment: i checked, its changed successfully except in the shell! i should quit then reload

Answer (score 2):

This is just transaction isolation. The shell session works inside a single transaction, which won't see updates from outside. Just quit the shell and reload, and you'll see the updated password.

Comment: in my case i want to get the effect without quitting, because i am using ftp server (pyftpdlib) to use django authentications, if any user changed his password thats mean i should restart the server each time!